# Java - output of method

Tags: java

Looking at the output of this particular method is confusing to me. I'm trying to understand exactly what it's doing.

This is the method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j==5) {
        break;
    }
    if ((j==0) || (i==0)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!((j*i % 3) != 0)) {
    System.out.println(j*i);
    }
}
```

}

I know what the output is but I'm still not sure how it's working, which is why I am asking here. So, This method will go through j until it reaches 5, then it breaks.

Then it increments i, j is 0. J != 5 so it doesn't break, j == 0 so continue
But then J becomes 3 and I is 1. This is where I'm lost. Where did 3 come from??

I was using this to print out what was going on behind the scenes

```
    public static void tester() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (j==5) {
                System.out.println("j == 5, breaking");
                break;
            }
            if ((j==0) || (i==0)) {
                System.out.println("J is " + j);
                System.out.println("I is " + i);
                System.out.println("j or i == 0, continuing");
                continue;
            }
            if (!((j*i % 3) != 0)) {
                System.out.println("J is " + j);
                System.out.println("I is " + i);
                System.out.println(j*i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output is as follows:

```
J is 0

I is 0

j or i == 0, continuing

J is 1

I is 0

j or i == 0, continuing

J is 2

I is 0

j or i == 0, continuing

J is 3

I is 0

j or i == 0, continuing

J is 4

I is 0

j or i == 0, continuing

j == 5, breaking


J is 0

I is 1

j or i == 0, continuing

J is 3

I is 1

3

j == 5, breaking


J is 0

I is 2

j or i == 0, continuing

J is 3

I is 2

6

j == 5, breaking


J is 0

I is 3


j or i == 0, continuing

J is 1

I is 3

3

J is 2

I is 3

6

J is 3

I is 3

9

J is 4

I is 3

12

j == 5, breaking
```

Comment: J is 3 because you only print when j*i modulus 3 is 0

Comment: The 3 comes from the fact that it loops round inside the j for loop and you don't have any prints in there. Add a print inside the j for loop to see this. Also this code is terrifying.

Comment: What about to run with debugger and see what is going on?

Comment: This is unreadable: `!((j*i % 3) != 0)`. Simply use `(j*i % 3) == 0`

Comment: Haha I know the code is terrifying. It was on an exam (which I got partially wrong), and now I'm trying to figure out why! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `3` (and later on, the `6`), is occurring from this piece of code...

```
        if (!((j*i % 3) != 0)) {
            System.out.println("J is " + j);
            System.out.println("I is " + i);
            System.out.println(j*i);
        }
```

Effectively what `!((j*i % 3) != 0)` is saying is, when `j*i/3` has a remainder of `0`, it runs the code within this `if` statement. In other words, it runs this `if` code whenever `j*i` is a multiple of `3` (`3`, `6`, `9`, `12`)

The logic is hard to follow - it'd be better to write it like this...

```
        if ((j*i % 3) == 0) {
            System.out.println("J is " + j);
            System.out.println("I is " + i);
            System.out.println(j*i);
        }
```

In the original way, all the `!` symbols and multiple brackets/braces make it hard to read.

Comment: Thanks, this was code on an exam so I guess he was trying to make it annoyingly confusing. The two !'s definitely through me off, which is why I got the question partially wrong XD

Comment: Well he succeeded in making it hard to understand - it was messing with my head too :-)

Answer (score 1):

When j=2 and i=1, you have `!((j*i % 3) != 0)` returning false so it doesn't go in that condition (and none other either) and there is no output. That's why it appears to jump over j=2. Add an additional `System.out.println()` when j==2 and you'll see it appear.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your next output is at `i=1` `j = 3` is because for `j=2` and `j=1` all 3 of the `ifs` are false.

you have

1. `j=1` `i=1`
2. `1*1 % 3` which is `1`
3. `1 != 0` which is `true`
4. `!(true)` which is `false`

and

1. `j=2` `i=1`
2. `2*1 % 3` which is `2`
3. `2 != 0` which is `true`
4. `!(true)` which is `false`

finally

1. `j=3` `i=1`
2. `3*1 % 3` which is `0`
3. `0 != 0` which is `false`
4. `!(false)` which is `true`

so you print out the answer

If you want to see everything I would move the

```
System.out.println("J is " + j); 
System.out.println("I is " + i);
```

outside of the `ifs` that way it's printed for every iteration of the loops